# reading the environment when executing ELF IFUNC dispatch functions

Tags: c, linux, glibc, elf

The IFUNC mechanism in recent ELF tools on (at least) Linux allows to choose a implementation of a function at runtime. Look at the iunc attribute in the GCC documentation for more detailed description: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html
  Another description of IFUNC mecanism : http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=167

I would like to choose my implementation depending on the value of an environment variable. However, my experiments show me that the libc (at least the part about environment) is not yet initialized when the resolver function is run. So, the classical interfaces (extern char**environ or getenv()) do not work.

Does anybody know how to access the environment of a program in Linux at very early stage ? The environment is setup by the kernel at the execve(2) system call, so it is already somewhere (but where exactly ?) in the program address space at early initialization.

Thanks in advance
    Vincent

Program to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char** environ;
char** save_environ;
char* toto;
int saved=0;

extern int fonction ();

int fonction1 () {
return 1;
}

int fonction2 () {
return 2;
}

static typeof(fonction) * resolve_fonction (void) {
saved=1;
save_environ=environ;
toto=getenv("TOTO");
/* no way to choose between fonction1 and fonction2 with the TOTO envvar */
return fonction1;
}

int fonction () __attribute__ ((ifunc ("resolve_fonction")));

void print_saved() {
printf("saved: %dn", saved);
if (saved) {
printf("prev environ: %pn", save_environ);
printf("prev TOTO: %sn", toto);
}
}

int main() {

print_saved();
printf("main environ: %pn", environ);
printf("main environ[0]: %sn", environ[0]);
printf("main TOTO: %sn", getenv("TOTO"));
printf("main value: %dn", fonction());

return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
$ gcc -Wall -g ifunc.c -o ifunc
$ env TOTO=ok ./ifunc
saved: 1
prev environ: (nil)
prev TOTO: (null)
main environ: 0x7fffffffe288
main environ[0]: XDG_VTNR=7
main TOTO: ok
main value: 1
$
```

In the resolver function, `environ` is NULL and `getenv("TOTO")` returns NULL. In the `main` function, the information is here.

Comment: You are operating at a level below the C runtime. So you need to read the code of libc and find out where it gets the environment from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Function Pointer

I found no way to use env in early stage legally. Resolver function runs in linker even earlier, than preinit_array functions. The only legal way to resolve this is to use function pointer and decide what function to use in  function of .preinit_array section:

```
extern char** environ;
int(*f)();

void preinit(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
        f = f1;
        environ = envp; // actually, it is done a bit later
        char *v = getenv("TOTO");
        if (v && strcmp(v, "ok") == 0) {
                f = f2;
        }
}

__attribute__((section(".preinit_array"))) typeof(preinit) *__preinit = preinit;
```

### ifunc & GNU ld inners

Glibc's linker ld contains a local symbol **_environ** and it is initialized, but it is rather hard to extract it. There is another way I found, but it is a bit tricky and rather unreliable.

At linker's entry point **_start** only stack is initialized. Program arguments and environmental values are sent to the process via stack. Arguments are stored in the following order:

argc, argv, argv + 1, ..., argv + argc - 1, NULL, ENV...

Linker ld shares a global symbol **_dl_argv**, which points to this place on the stack. With the help of it we can extract all the needful variables:

```
extern char** environ;
extern char **_dl_argv;

char** get_environ() {
    int argc = *(int*)(_dl_argv - 1);
    char **my_environ = (char**)(_dl_argv + argc + 1);
    return my_environ;
}

typeof(f1) * resolve_f() {
    environ = get_environ();
    const char *var = getenv("TOTO");
    if (var && strcmp(var, "ok") == 0) {
        return f2;
    }
    return f1;
}

int f() __attribute__((ifunc("resolve_f")));
```